# Fatal Exception applicationId is null Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, fatal-error

This is my second question in SO, I have a problem about Fatal Main error. Before I ask it, I found some other problem in SO, but what I found is about Facebook app
This is my error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationId is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
```

But, I have a class that declared it

```
package com.example.michael.eksperimen6chatting;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 03/12/2015.
 */
public class ChattApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.initialize(this, "urkcFwvUmgSYvuOFTInJmkA3iWv0ArV3XT128TNb", "WvBC0cnGXHkVhTBbkFwLyxGDRgqR6qC8ft7DIleT");
    }
}
```

and this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.michael.eksperimen6chatting" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserList"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Chat">

        </activity>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Did I miss something here, can anyone help me? Gratia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying `ChattApp` Application class name in your `AndroidManifest.xml`'s `<application>` tag.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="com.example.michael.eksperimen6chatting.ChattApp">
  ....
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.parse.Parse;
    import android.app.Application;

    public class ChattApp extends Application {
      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
      }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.michael.eksperimen6chatting.ChattApp"
.
.
.
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mate. But sorry, your advice is good, but not right for mine. Gratia Tibi